# Buttons on a Panel in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel that has 3 buttons adjacent to each other.  Collectively, the buttons are the same size as the panel.  How do I make the Panel1_MouseLeave event fire, since the buttons take up all of the panel?

Comment: Make the buttons smaller?

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the buttons, the Panel1_MouseLeave will get fired. You could use a combination of button_MouseLeave and Panel1_MouseLeave to determine when the mouse has actually left the control.

Or as suggested above, make the buttons 1px smaller than the panel. When the MouseLeave() gets fired, check the mouse location. If it is in the bound of the panel, you have not left. If it is outside the bounds, then you have left.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I could not get it to work.  FYI, I could not find the right combination of button_MouseLeave and Panel1_MouseLeave to make it work, although I am sure that it is possible, it sounds like a great solution.  Making the buttons 1px smaller worked, but if you move the mouse too fast, it skips right over it, even if I made the buttons even smaller.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to your form and check the mouse position:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  If Panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(Panel1.PointToClient(MousePosition)) Then
    If Not insidePanel Then
      insidePanel = True
      // do something...
    End If
  Else
    If insidePanel Then
      insidePanel = False
      // do something
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```